# trigger is called in beginning

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a sound that gets triggered with OnTriggerEnter, and picking up whether sound is playing to turn sprite renderer on/off.

For some reason, when I start the game, the sound starts playing (which should only be getting called by the trigger).

I checked the trigger with the players tag and debug.log to console, and found that the trigger method isn't being called at the start. But, for some reason, the sound is getting played at the start and when I hit the trigger(but not turning the sprite renderer back on).

FlagScript

```
#pragma strict

var Sprite2 : Sprite; //second sprite to renderer

var sr : SpriteRenderer;

var hasBeenHit : boolean = false;
var flagCollisionSounderies: AudioSource;
var flagCollisionSound : AudioClip = null;
private var applauseRef: ApplauseScript;
private var go: GameObject;

var count : int = 0;


function Start () {
//access the spriteRenderer
flagCollisionSound = flagCollisionSounderies.clip;
sr = GetComponent(SpriteRenderer);
go = GameObject.Find("ClapMaster");
applauseRef = go.GetComponent(typeof(ApplauseScript));
//Debug.Log("bool: "+flagCollisionSounderies.isPlaying); //true already

}



function OnTriggerEnter2D(coll: Collider2D){
//Debug.Log("flagtriggered");
//change the flag to other flag
sr.sprite = Sprite2;
if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
    Debug.Log("poos");
    if (hasBeenHit == false){
        GameMaster.setFlags(GameMaster.getFlags()-1);
        GameMaster.addPointsToScore(100);

        if (flagCollisionSound != null){
            flagCollisionSounderies.PlayClipAtPoint(flagCollisionSound, transform.position);
            //Debug.Log("bool:" + flagCollisionSounderies.isPlaying);
            applauseRef.animRenderer.enabled = true;

        }
    }
}
hasBeenHit = true;  
}

function Update(){

    if(!flagCollisionSounderies.isPlaying){
        applauseRef.animRenderer.enabled = false;
        //applauseRef.playApplauseAnim = false;
    }else{
        //Debug.Log("sounderies     detecteddFsdlfkjsdlfksjdflksdjflkj1123123");
    applauseRef.animRenderer.enabled = true;
    //applauseRef.playApplauseAnim = true;
}


}
```

Applause Script

```
#pragma strict

var SpriteLoad: Sprite[];
static var animSprites : Sprite[];

static var playerScriptRef: newplayer;

static var animRenderer: SpriteRenderer;
//private static var i : int = 7;
private static var frame : int = 3;
private static var Ymove: float = 0f;
private static var goingUp: boolean = false;
static var playApplauseAnim: boolean;


function Start(){
    animRenderer = GetComponent(SpriteRenderer);
    animSprites = SpriteLoad;
    playerScriptRef = GameObject.Find("Player 1").GetComponent(newplayer);
    //animRenderer.enabled = false;
    //playApplauseAnim = false;

}

    function Update(){
        PicMover();
        frame = (frame +1 ) % 4;
        animRenderer.sprite = animSprites[frame];   

}   



static function PicMover(){

    if(Ymove < 20 && goingUp){
        Ymove++;
    }else if(Ymove > -20 && !goingUp){
        Ymove--;
    }else if(Ymove == 20){
        goingUp = false;
    }else if(Ymove == -20){
        goingUp = true;
    }
    animRenderer.transform.position = new Vector2(10,10);
}
```

Comment: Check your audio source, there is an option somewhere to "play on awake"... Disable this and your sound shouldn't play at the start.

Comment: yea, I've unticked that on the UI, but still happening for some reason :(

Comment: Okay, so the problem was that I hadnt applied it to the rest of the prefab. Thanks for the intuition. Now the problem is that isPlaying doesnt seem to be picking up when the sound is triggered.